# read two different chars in a java program

Tags: java

How to read two different chars
in a program..

I read x,but while reading choice it shows runtime InputMismatch error..

```
public static void main(String ar[]) throws IOException{
    char x,choice;
    int temp,spoilt=0;
    int count[]=new int[5];
    DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(System.in);
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    do{
        System.out.print("Enter your vote(1 to 5):");
        x=(char)sc.nextInt();
        temp=Character.getNumericValue(x);
        if(temp>=1&&temp<=5){
            count[temp-1]++;
        }else{
          spoilt++;
        }
        System.out.print("Do you want to continue voting..\n");
        System.out.print("Press Y or N:");
        choice=(char)sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("   "+ch);
    }while(choice=='Y'||choice=='y');
    for(int i=0;i<count.length;i++)
        System.out.print("Number of votes by canditate"+(i+1)+""+count[i]+"\n");
    System.out.print("Spoilt votes:"+spoilt);
}
```

Comment: what do you think `nextInt` would read? a character or an integer...

Comment: nextLine reads string,i want to read char so i used nextInt.

Answer (score 2):

In order to read a character, please try simply: `reader.next().charAt(0)`

Answer (score 1):

To consume strictly one character you could use:

```
char c = reader.next(".").charAt(0);
```